# Live Lists example DomTokenList values

Tags: javascript, list, console

I have a question regarding the console output of the DomTokenList(in general live lists).
Why does the first console output also show the 3 values instead of 2.
Although I added the third class afterwards.
I already set a timeout but the result is the same.

Thanks & Have a nice Sunday

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <style>
.eins {background-color:orange;height:50px;}
.zwei {color:red;}
.drei {width:50px;}

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="eins zwei">JS</div>

    <script>
var eins=document.querySelector("div");
var klasse=eins.classList;
console.log(klasse);
setTimeout(b,1000);
function b(){
eins.classList.add("drei");
console.log(klasse);}

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Screenshot console output]

Comment: The browser's console only displays whatever it needs to at a given time. When you expanded the list, the browser then fetched the contents and displayed it to you, but since the list had already been modified, the new contents are displayed instead. You can see in the first line of the output, it actually shows you it only contains two elements and shows you what they are because that was printed when the list only contained those two elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks good to me, please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCQP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

It will be updated later. If you set the delay to say 10 seconds and open the list immediately, it contains only 2 items. But it's even easier if you use `console.log (klasse.length)`. It gave me `2` ... `3`.